# SOAP webservice with PHP: could not connect to host

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Please note that after much research I decided to write here since I couldn't pin-point the problem. Although it exists widely on the net. Sorry for that.

I'm trying to get a response using SOAP (see code below):

```
<?php 
$param = array(
        'USERID'=>'some_user',
        'PASSWORD'=>'some_pwd',
        'MARKETTYPE'=>'333',
        'INSTRUMENTTYPE'=>'C' 
    );

    $url = 'https://www.x/x/x/x.serviceagent?wsdl'; 

    try 
    {
        $soap_client = new SoapClient($url); 
        $soap_client->providedFunction($param);

    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();      
    }
?>
```

Note that this code is on my local wamp server. (I also tried it online on a beta site)
When I refresh the php file, I get the following 'Could not connect to host'.

I appreciate any help given.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to call the web service using SoapUI or any other language? It seems to be a problem with server and doesn't with client.

Comment: I'll try it and get back to you, although the SOAP request is given to me by the company that I'm to retrieve the data from.

Comment: After testing with SoapUI i got the following error: 
Error getting response: Connection to http://localhost:4554 refused

Comment: As I said it seems a server side problem.

Comment: I figured it out, I used __setLocation to change the soap address location...now it works